# MobileFirst Direct Update is not working for a specific version

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, checksum

We have just created a new version in MF which is 2.1.0. We generated a .apk and .ipa with the same version and the checksums match with the server.

Before we upload to 2.1.0 which is production we test by creating two other versions (1.2.1 & 1.2.2). We uploaded both packages with its respected version and the direct update worked on our devices so we went along and uploaded the production version.

For some reason this version uploaded correctly but in production the direct update didnt work.

What could be causing that certain versions dont work? Does MF has some sort of rule that if that version already existed in the past it wont work again?

Comment: Before it serves that archive to a mobile client, the server compares the client version with the plug-in version. If both versions are close enough (meaning that the three most significant digits are identical), Direct Update occurs normally. Otherwise, MobileFirst Server silently skips the update.
Can you verify this?

Comment: @VivinK Yes, we have and as I stated the same build worked on version 1.2.1 and 1.2.2 but didnt work on 2.1.0

Comment: Has the client side build changed between 1.2.1 , 1.2.2 and 2.1.0? By change, I mean iFix or plugin level

Comment: @VivinK nope, same build for all 3